# XML SAX Parser error: value must not contain the '<' character - pointing to TNS value without '<' character

Tags: java, xml, spring, jboss, sax

I want to deploy war file into JBOSS6 with the following spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver />

    <property name="url"
                    value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.com)(PORT=15210)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXXX.COM)))" />
    <property name="username" value="xxx" />
    <property name="password" value="xxx" />
</bean>

<!-- External configuration -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:application-default.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<import resource="applicationContext-common.xml" />
</beans>
```

SAX Parser validation is failing with this message:

```
13:45:12,767 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (MSC service thread 1-4) Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
13:45:12,791 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-4) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 16 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 4; The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "property" must not contain the '<' character.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP6-1709.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP6-1709.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:89) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 4; The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "property" must not contain the '<' character.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 21 more

13:45:12,793 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/xxxxxxxxxx]] (MSC service thread 1-4) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 16 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 4; The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "property" must not contain the '<' character.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP6-1709.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP6-1709.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:89) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 4; The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "property" must not contain the '<' character.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 21 more

13:45:12,800 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Error listenerStart
13:45:12,801 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Context [/xxxxx] startup failed due to previous errors
13:45:12,801 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/xxxxx]] (MSC service thread 1-4) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
13:45:12,802 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./xxxxxx: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./xxxxxx: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:94)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
```

I'm getting the same validation error when I used this online validation tool: http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

The error is clear - value must not contain the '<' character but the problem is that I do not see '<' character in this text pointed by the parser:

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.com)(PORT=15210)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXXX.COM)))

I tried to enclose this text with:

```
<![CDATA[ ]]>
```

but the result is the same.
Please help me what is wrong with this XML ?

Comment: First of all, try to close <beans> tag

Comment: Sorry it was a problem with formating of question I forgot 4 spaces in the last line of xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your driver class name you have missed to close the quote.

```
 <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
```

Comment: I feel really really stupid right now, but I the same time realy happy :) Thanks!

Comment: It's nothing wrong there it happens with everyone :) You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the line above missing a close quote

```
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver />
```