# "The value of attribute must not contain the '<' character" error

Tags: xml, ant

> BUILD FAILED
>
> C:\Users\acerpc\Documents\sample\build.xml:9: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 2; The value of attribute "encoding" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
>
> at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)

My XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" >
    <types>
        <members>Sample__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>35.0</version>
</package>
```

Comment: You likely have a missing quotation mark somewhere. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31610418/1078068).

Comment: Can you show your build.xml, or at least the relevant parts of it?